# Closing only particular FancyBox when having multiple Fancybox

Tags: fancybox, setinterval, getjson, fancybox-2

In a given page, I have multiple instances of Fancybox items that will show up an video when clicked on a link.

Apart from those, I have a function running every 5 seconds to get data from a URL and display another fancybox based on the return value.

The problem is that, as the setInterval function runs always, even if the actual video is played, it closes that video as I use $.fancybox.close().

All I wanted is to close only the fanybox identified by myModal.

This is the jQuery that I use.

```
$(document).ready(function() {           

    function myplugin() {             
         $.getJSON("get-status.php", function (data) {                        
             $.each(data, function (key, status) {   
                 if(status > 0) {
                    $("#myModal").fancybox().click();
                 }else{
                    $.fancybox.close(); // Works. But closes other open Fancybox if any
                    //$("#myModal").fancybox().close();    // Does not work
                 }
             });       
        });  
    };

    $(function() {
       setInterval(function() { myplugin() }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: someone please help.. surprise to see no help on this topic.

Comment: surprised? maybe because your question is not really clear.

Comment: I would be happy to provide more information on this. I have provided the code that I have used. Please let me know which one is not clear.

Comment: your condition `if(status > 0)` either opens or closes `#myModal` .... every 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes Sir. If status == 0 the fancybox identified by "#MyModal" only should be closed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not completely sure I understood your question, however since it's not very easy to know if `#myModal` is currently opened in fancybox (outside of the fancybox function itself), I would create a ***flag*** or ***switch*** that would be enabled from within a fancybox callback **IF** `#myModal` is the current element opened.

Then, from `myplugin()` I would validate if the ***switch*** is `true` (`#myModal` is the current element) and if so, close fancybox.

The script would look something like this (not tested because I don't really know what `myplugin()` does) :

```
// declare a switch to set if #myModal is open in fancybox
var myModal = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    function myplugin() {
        $.getJSON("get-status.php", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, status) {
                if (status > 0) {
                    $("#myModal").fancybox({
                        // use a callback to set the switch = true
                        afterShow: function () {
                            $(this.element).attr("id") == "myModal" ? myModal = true : myModal = false;
                        }
                    }).click();
                } else {
                    // close fancybox if myModal == true
                    if (myModal) {
                        $.fancybox().close();
                        myModal = false; // reset switch ?
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };
    // you don't need $(function(){ }); since you have declaread .ready() above
    setInterval(function () {
        myplugin()
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: You understanding on my question if correct. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this below one and it worked.

```
$("#myModal").parents("div .fancybox-skin").hide();
```

Please advice if there any other better way to do this.

Comment: I wouldn't say `hide` is the same as close

Comment: Yeah. But is there going to any difference in terms of performance? Or am I going to face any issue? This looks like a simpler approach. But again, I am going to accept your answer as its more comprehensive and good.